# Displaying mathematic expression using MathML with OpenMath

Tags: html, mathjax, mathml

First, what I'm trying to show is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mixed Markup</title>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            MathML: {
                extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-    AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <apply><csymbol cd="relation1">eq</csymbol>
        <apply><csymbol cd="fns1">domain</csymbol>
            <apply><csymbol cd="fns1">restriction</csymbol><ci>f</ci><ci>S</ci></apply>
        </apply>
        <ci>S</ci>
    </apply>
</math>

</body>
```

Second, when I try it on Chrome or IE, the representation is

[image]

That is, the words `domain` and `restriction` are displayed words as those are in HTML elements not as symbol.

It is just an example. Most of identifier or symbols using OpenMath are not displayed on web.

Sites which I referenced MathML [Content Markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter4.html)

[OpenMath Content Dictionaries](http://www.openmath.org/cdnames.html)

[OpenMath Content Dictionaries, fns1](http://www.openmath.org/cd/fns1.xhtml)

Please let me know, why... thanks

Comment: plus, the element `eq` of csymbol is shown as symbol `=` not a word it is.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger oh.. So Thank you  !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from [this issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1145), MathJax's Content MathML extension does not (fully) support Strict Content MathML; you are seeing a side effect of this.